# How to go back to the first window and make selenium webdriver interact with it?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm using Selenium-WebDriver, cucumber with Ruby API. I'm trying to close the last window and switch back to the default window to continue interact with this. But when I click on any button, I get the error : 'Unable to locate element'

```
`Then(/^Click the Twitter icon$/) do
  $driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
  $driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 2
  $driver.manage.delete_all_cookies
  $driver.get 'http://url.com'
  $driver.manage.window.maximize

  #Click control that opens new window
  $driver.find_element(:xpath => "xpath_goes_here").click
  #Switch to window
  $driver.switch_to.window( $driver.window_handles.last ){
    #Do actions in new window
    $driver.find_element(:xpath => "xpath_goes_here").click
    $driver.close
  }
  wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 40)
  wait.until {$driver.find_element(:xpath => "xpath_goes_here").click}
end`
```

Comment: This question doesn't have much to do with Cucumber. Mostly Selenium Webdriver behavior. I'd refactor it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the reference or id (handle in terms of selenium webdriver) of window is set to the new window. This reference in selenium webdriver is not changed when you close the new window.

This can be determined by calling window_handle function of selenium webdriver before and after closing window. You will get the id of the window if this method is called before closing the window. But after closing the window, if you try to call it then selenium webdriver will throw error saying "no such window: target window already closed from unknown error: web view not found"

So, if you want to get back to the default window then you must switch window handle again before doing any operation on that window. Add following code snippet after closing new window:

```
 $driver.switch_to.window( $driver.window_handles.last )
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,OarpitO. But the actions that i do in new window are put into a block with {} and it means that i should automatically switched back to the default window after the block is over, shoudn't I?

Comment: Yes, it should work. I tried your code snippet with chrome driver and it worked. Which browser's driver are you initiating and are you using the correct xpath for finding the element after closing the window?

Comment: I'm using driver for firefox. Seems like i found out what was happening: the xpathes that i used were correct but each time when the selenium webdriver tried to interact with the default window i got the error 'Element  currently is not visible' so what i did i just added $driver.navigate.refresh after the block of code. And it worked! Woohoooo! Seems like it is StaleElement. Thank you !

Comment: Cool, awesome. This may be because DOM might have changed when switching to new window and coming back to old one. Glad to help you out.